# PHP TextBox Value Before Submission

Tags: php, html, concrete5

I'm building a registration form in Concrete5 but beforehand I need to retreive the User Attributes.

I'm using hidden input to get the values as so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="akID[<?php echo UserAttributeKey::getByHandle('school')->getAttributeKeyID(); ?>][value]" value='<?php echo $_POST['full_name']; ?>'/>
```

However I can only get the value if I make a mistake beforehand, i.e. incorrect confirm password and then resubmit the form.

Any ideas on how to get the values without doing this?

Kind Regards

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you want to check whether the `password` and `confirm password` fields values are same or not.. For it, you can use JavaScript or JQuery to achieve it...

Comment: @phpfresher Sorry, its a hard question to try to explain, I have to force an error during registration and then resubmit the form inorder for these values to be set

Comment: You mean, it has to show an error and then the form has to submit automatically ?????

Comment: @phpfresher Validation will kick in when they notice there is an error, I then complete validation and then manually press the submit button, which will then display set these attributes. However, I dont want to force an error, I just want the attributes to be sent on first submission. I think its something to do with $_POST or the way I get the value from the other textbox

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit confusing.

First let me explain why it doesn't work the way you want it to.

You are giving your hidden field a value from $_POST. $_POST only exists once you actually post the form. So on first load of the page, $_POST doesn't exist so $_POST['full_name'] is null.
When you submit the form and there is an error however, the same page reloads but this time $_POST exists since the page reloads after submitting the form.

Here's what is confusing. If on reload $_POST['full_name'] has a value it means you already have a 'full_name' field probably as a text input box. Why then do you want to have a hidden field with the exact same value?

If what you want in this hidden field is the value of a user attribute you need to do 2 things:
1- make sure the user is logged in, else no attributes are available
2- get the user info object to get the attribute value from like so:

```
$u = new User();
$ui = UserInfo::getByID($u->getUserID());
```

2- modify the value of the hidden field like so:

```
value="<?php echo $ui->getAttribute('attribute_handle'); ?>"
```